# How to use requirejs to load a directory recursivelly?

Tags: javascript, recursion, callback, requirejs

How to use [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) to require all files on directory and the subdirectories of this one recursivelly?

For example, if we have a directory like:

```
vendor
    vendor1
        vendor11.js
    vendor2
        vendor21.js
        vendor22.js
        vendor23.js
    vendor3
        vendor31.js
```

How can we load the entire directory vendor? Using a function like `require(['vendor/*'], myCallbackFunction)`?

This function should load the equivalent:

```
require(
    ['vendor/vendor1/vendor11.js'],
    require(
        ['vendor/vendor2/vendor21.js'],
        require(
            ['vendor/vendor2/vendor22.js'],
            ...and so on
                ... require(
                    ['vendor/vendor3/vendor31.js'],
                    myCallbackFunction
                )
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

RequireJS does not provide facilities to load modules according to a pattern. What you pass to `require` has to be a list of actual module names.

One option would be when you build your application, scan for modules according to the pattern you want and create a module that loads all of the other modules. For instance, it could be named `'vendor_all'` and could contain:

```
define(['vendor/vendor1/vendor11', 'vendor/vendor2/vendor21', ...]);
```

You would then do `require(['vendor_all'], function () {...});` or put `'vendor_all`' in the list of dependencies of another module.